# Should the use of safe navigation operator be unit tested with both scenarios (object exist + object nil)?

Tags: ruby, rspec, bdd

consider the following code:

```
class Child
  belongs_to :some_parent, optional: true
  def status
    some_parent&.calculate_status
  end
end
```

Is that trivial enough to not write a unit test for each scenario or is it better to write scenarios such as:

```
describe '#status' do 
  context 'when some_parent does not exist' do
    ## assume let/before block exist to properly set this up
    it 'returns nil' do
      expect(subject.status).to_be nil
    end
  end 

  context 'when some_parent exists' do
    ## assume let/before block exist to properly set this up
    it 'returns the value from some_parent' do
      expect(subject.status).to eql('expected status')
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Testing is a good habit, but there is no need to test anything. It is totally up to you and your team to decide what you want to test and what test coverage is acceptable. It might be around 80%, or just 0%, or always 100%. I am voting to close this question because answers will be highly opinion-based.

Comment: @spickermann I generally agree with you, but then I thought about substituting "testing" with "wearing seatbelts". Wearing seatbelts is a personally choice that is subjective, but there is an objective discussion around whether seat belt usage reduces risk of fatalities. Likewise, I believe there is still discussion to be had on the validity or the trivialness of unit testing a relatively new ruby feature. Do we end up just testing the language or is there merit for these types of tests? I think those who answered have contributed to the meaningful discussion.

Comment: _"Should the safe navigation operator be unit tested?"_ – no, that's something Ruby (the language) should have tests for. And you don't test the safe navigation operator in your example. What you do test is whether your code works when `some_parent` happens to be `nil`. I think testing that aspect is perfectly fine because it allows you to refactor your code later on. Or, from a TDD perspective: the failing test would be the reason to add the `&` in the first place.

Comment: @Stefan - updated to reflect the core question. Thank you.

Comment: I think the core question is _"should I test whether my method still works as expected if `some_parent` is nil?"_. And I see little to no reason to _not_ test that :-) Your test would be the same if your method would be `some_parent.calculate_status if some_parent` or if you'd have a guard clause or active support's `try`. It's not specific to the safe navigation operator at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not necessarily a matter of there being a factual answer to this. How much code coverage you need is up to you. However if we reframe your question as *Is there less code coverage when not testing the `nil` state?* then the answer is **yes** because they are two different branches and each must be evaluated separately.

**When `some_parent` is `nil`:**

```rb
some_parent&.calculate_status
#          ^ short circuits here and we branch to nil
```

**When `some_parent` exists:**

```rb
some_parent&.calculate_status
#           ^ method evaluation occurs and we branch to the method
```

A simple way to verify this is to test it using [simplecov](https://github.com/simplecov-ruby/simplecov). Here's an example app that can verify it:

```rb
# Gemfile

source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rspec'
gem 'simplecov'
gem 'simplecov-console'
```

```rb
# app.rb

# We create the equivalent of your ++belongs_to++ call
# with these classes
class Parent
  def calculate_status
    "in parent"
  end
end

class Child
  attr_reader :some_parent

  def initialize(parent = nil)
    @some_parent = parent
  end

  def status
    @some_parent&.calculate_status
  end
end
```

```rb
# app_spec.rb

require "simplecov"
require "simplecov-console"

SimpleCov.start { enable_coverage :branch }
SimpleCov.formatter = SimpleCov::Formatter::Console

require_relative "app"

RSpec.describe "#status" do
  context "when some_parent does not exist" do
    it "returns nil" do
      expect(Child.new.status).to be nil
    end
  end

  context "when some_parent exists" do
    it "returns the value from some_parent" do
      expect(Child.new(Parent.new).status).to eq("in parent")
    end
  end
end
```

Then we run the tests:

```bash
bundle exec rspec app_spec.rb
..

Finished in 0.00401 seconds (files took 0.09368 seconds to load)
2 examples, 0 failures


COVERAGE: 100.00% -- 9/9 lines in 1 files
BRANCH COVERAGE: 100.00% -- 2/2 branches in 1 branches
```

We've tested both branches and have 100% coverage. If we tell it to run only one of the two specs we get a different result:

```bash
bundle exec rspec app_spec.rb:14
Run options: include {:locations=>{"./app_spec.rb"=>[14]}}
.

Finished in 0.00141 seconds (files took 0.08878 seconds to load)
1 example, 0 failures


COVERAGE:  88.89% -- 8/9 lines in 1 files
BRANCH COVERAGE:  50.00% -- 1/2 branches in 1 branches

+----------+--------+-------+--------+---------+-----------------+----------+-----------------+------------------+
| coverage | file   | lines | missed | missing | branch coverage | branches | branches missed | branches missing |
+----------+--------+-------+--------+---------+-----------------+----------+-----------------+------------------+
|  88.89%  | app.rb | 9     | 1      | 3       |  50.00%         | 2        | 1               | 15[then]         |
+----------+--------+-------+--------+---------+-----------------+----------+-----------------+------------------+
```

Or the other spec:

```bash
bundle exec rspec app_spec.rb:20
Run options: include {:locations=>{"./app_spec.rb"=>[20]}}
.

Finished in 0.00128 seconds (files took 0.08927 seconds to load)
1 example, 0 failures


COVERAGE: 100.00% -- 9/9 lines in 1 files
BRANCH COVERAGE:  50.00% -- 1/2 branches in 1 branches

+----------+--------+-------+--------+---------+-----------------+----------+-----------------+------------------+
| coverage | file   | lines | missed | missing | branch coverage | branches | branches missed | branches missing |
+----------+--------+-------+--------+---------+-----------------+----------+-----------------+------------------+
| 100.00%  | app.rb | 9     | 0      |         |  50.00%         | 2        | 1               | 15[else]         |
+----------+--------+-------+--------+---------+-----------------+----------+-----------------+------------------+
```

So if you want full *branch coverage* then write both specs.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned elsewhere, code coverage standards for your team are for you to determine. You need to understand both the diminishing returns argument AND the "what would you like me to not test" argument, then make a call.

However, there is a different aspect of your question that deserves attention: *Is code that uses the safe navigation operator more or less complex that code that does not use it?*

The safe navigation operator was added to Ruby in order to reduce the `undefined method 'x' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)` errors caused by Law of Demeter violations. Those violations are common in Rails apps due to the way you append queries and clauses together in ActiveRecord. In one sense, the operator makes for less code. And, generally speaking, less code makes for less complexity. But, let's take a look at this and two other approaches and compare complexity.

If we compare safe navigation to the old way of using `&&` to a third way (using the `NullObject` pattern):

```rb
# safe_navigation.rb

class Parent
  def calculate_status
    "in parent"
  end
end

class Child
  attr_reader :some_parent

  def initialize(parent = nil)
    @parent = parent
  end

  def status_with_safe_navigation
    parent&.calculate_status
  end

  def status_with_conditional
    parent && parent.calculate_status
  end

  def status_with_null_object
    return "" unless parent

    parent.calculate_status
  end
end
```

We get the following from flog:

```
~/so > flog -am safe_navigation.rb
    12.3: flog total
     3.1: flog/method average

     4.0: Child#status_with_conditional      safe_navigation.rb:22-23
     3.7: Child#status_with_null_object      safe_navigation.rb:26-29
     2.5: Child#status_with_safe_navigation  safe_navigation.rb:18-19
     2.2: Child#initialize                   safe_navigation.rb:14-15
```

So, yes, in isolation, the safe navigation operator is the least complex solution. However, when you consider that the client of the `Child` class must now also handle `nil`, the overall complexity scenario changes. Let's add a `ClientOfChild` class and look at the complexity there:

Here's the class:

```rb
class ClientOfChild
  def call_status_with_safe_navigation
    result = Client.new.status_with_safe_navigation

    result.nil? ? "" : result
  end

  def call_status_with_conditional
    result = Client.new.status_with_conditional

    result.nil? ? "" : result
  end

  def call_status_with_null_object
    Client.new.status_with_null_object
  end
end
```

In this code, the code with and without the safe navigation operator must handle `nil`, but the `NullObject` based code does not.

Here's the flog:

```
~/so > flog -am safe_navigation.rb
    22.4: flog total
     3.2: flog/method average

     4.0: Child#status_with_conditional                   safe_navigation.rb:22-23
     3.8: ClientOfChild#call_status_with_safe_navigation  safe_navigation.rb:34-37
     3.8: ClientOfChild#call_status_with_conditional      safe_navigation.rb:40-43
     3.7: Child#status_with_null_object                   safe_navigation.rb:26-29
     2.5: Child#status_with_safe_navigation               safe_navigation.rb:18-19
     2.4: ClientOfChild#call_status_with_null_object      safe_navigation.rb:46-47
     2.2: Child#initialize                                safe_navigation.rb:14-15
```

Now, looking at the total flog for each path we get:

```
 * With safe navigation = 2.5 + 3.8 = 6.3
 * With conditional     = 4.0 + 3.8 = 7.8
 * With NullObject      = 3.7 + 2.4 = 6.1
```

Because this is an oversimplification of real code, the differences in flog are small. But, the overall winner is the `NullObject` pattern. You'll find that with the more complex the method, the further apart these numbers will grow.

For this reason and so that I don't break the Law of Demeter in my code, I choose the `NullObject` pattern rather than using the safe navigation operator (except in ActiveReccord queries, because, well... Rails).